# Conditional extend tag for Swig with Express.js and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swig-template

Does anyone know how to make the extend tag for the Swig templating engine conditional or able to use a passed variable.

Instead of this:

```
{% extends '../layouts/layout.view' %}
```

I would like to do this

```
{% extends layout %}
```

Whilst rendering the file with this in express.js

```
res.render('jobs/index', { title: 'Jobs', layout: '../layouts/layout.view' });
```

Anyone did this before? Make the template extension conditional or pass a variable instead of a string. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Looking at the code, I'd say it's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this. At least I got what I wanted by changing a couple of lines.

What the solution essentially does is pass the `locals` parameter from the `renderFile` function to the `compileFile` function as such:

```
  this.renderFile = function (pathName, locals, cb) {
    if (cb) {
      exports.compileFile(pathName, locals, function (err, fn) { 
        if (err) {
          cb(err);
          return; 
       }
       cb(null, fn(locals));
     });
     return;
   }

   return exports.compileFile(pathName, locals)(locals);
 };
```

This happens on line `514` and line `524` of the `/lib/swig.js` file. Locals essentially becomes `options`

Then I only added this at line `405` in the same file

```
if(options.layout) 
  parentName = options.layout;
```

Whilst calling the res.render command in the route definition of express, I just add a layout option with the relative location of the layout.

```
res.render('index', { title: 'Express', layout: 'layouts/main.layout' });
```

This solved the problem for me completely. Maintaining normal `{% extend %}` functionality (when not overriding it with the `layout` option) whilst being able to set the layout dynamically.

The only drawback is that `layout` becomes a reserved option, you could refactor this to not be a problem I think.

Hope this helps someone. Two line changes and two lines of code made dynamic layouts possible for me. The performance is the same.

Comment: This helped me alot. But I came across a problem when the templates are cached. I got around this by adding the layout name to the cache key in the `compile` function of `lib/swig.js`:
`if (options.layout && key !== null) { key += options.layout;}`

Answer (score 2):

Conditional extends are not allowed in Swig. This is by-design for faster template rendering and better pre-compiling. When a template is parsed, it's parent-chain is resolved and compiled together at once for the given template, removing any necessary steps needing to be taken every subsequent time the template is run with different local contexts.

An alternate solution, though not very pretty, would be to use includes: Put your main content into a single file, but render two separate files, depending on what layout you want to use:

When you want layout 1, render this file:

```
{% extends "layout1.html" %}
{% block body %}
    {% include "content.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

And, when you want layout 2, render this file:

```
{% extends "layout2.html" %}
{% block body %}
    {% include "content.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Yeah, later realized something like this could be a solution.

Comment: Thanks Paul for your answer, I realise this is the way with the current setup. It seems handy though (based on authentication roles maybe) to render different layouts for the same contents. Will try this and investigate further, maybe there is another solution. I am trying to prevent duplicate html..